# Record my desktop in mp4 format

Tags: mp4, recordmydesktop, desktop-recording, video-recording

How do I record my desktop interaction (video) and audio directly in MP4 format?

I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: @Zanna is there a way to set this question to be one of those community things where there is no single answer and people can just vote up the most popular one at the time?

Comment: I can make the question "community wiki" but I don't think that will be useful. The effects are that authors receive no reputation for votes on their posts, and users with at least 100 rep can edit without review. Neither of these seems useful here. It tends to discourage people from answering too.

Comment: @Zanna I think the problem is that as Ubuntu evolves, this answer too will evolve and will have more than one solution and no best solution. People may find benefit in checking out each of the highest vote solutions. This is why I think a Community Wiki would be useful for this type of question.

Comment: I get that, but in my experience making a post community wiki doesn't help to keep the answers updated, and nor does it affect voting. Having a post be *not* community wiki encourages new answers. But it's up to you - I can do it if you want!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools, but first you should ensure you have the MP4 codecs installed. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) for instructions.

Once that is done, there are a number of tools available to you:

1. RecordMyDesktop

   ```
   sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
   ```
2. Other tools referenced [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screencast) - Istanbul, Kazam. There is also [xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: gtk-RecordMyDesktop didn't have a way that I saw to save to MP4.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/audio -f x11grab -s 1280x1024 -r 3 -aq 50 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mp4
```

This records both sound and video of my screen. I have an attached monitor, so :0.0 is that monitor. The -r 3 keeps the file size smaller by doing 3 frames per second, which causes the mouse to jerk around slightly, but is suitable for tutorials. Increase that 3 towards 30 for much higher quality (but larger file size). The -aq 50 stands for audio quality at 50%, which is suitable for listening to tutorials on your laptop, but not suitable for like a large conference, where removing the -aq option might be best.

Comment: does not work for me, I get a video only showing the first screen, no changes

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your comment on the answer about installing recordmydesktop, that application does not (currently) allow saving the output in mp4 format.

The solution that worked for me was to install Kazam. This allows screen recording (screencasting as they call it) and you can configure the output codec. MP4 is an option here.

```
sudo apt install kazam
```

Once this is done, you can record and even edit the output in avidemux.